# Cohomologies of $\Omega^k_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ and $\bigwedge\nolimits^k T_{\mathbb{P}^n}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

How to compute cohomologies of the sheaves of differential $k$-forms $\Omega^k_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ and exterior power of the tangent sheaf $\bigwedge\nolimits^k T_{\mathbb{P}^n}$? I am interested in purely algebraic way, without Dolbeaut cohomologies etc. 
There are Euler exact sequences
 $$ 0 \to \Omega^1_{\mathbb P^n} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1)^{\oplus n+1} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} \to 0,$$

$$0 \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^{n}} \to \mathcal O (1)^{\oplus (n+1)} \to \mathcal T_{\mathbb P^n} \to 0,$$ 
from which it is easy to compute cohomologies of $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ and $T_{\mathbb{P}^n}$. Is it possible to write analogous sequences for $\Omega^k_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ and $\bigwedge\nolimits^k T_{\mathbb{P}^n}$?

Is it possible to use Koszul complex?

Comment: For the cotangent version, you can take the *k*th exterior power of the Euler exact sequence for $\Omega^1$ as in Hirzebruch, *Topological methods in algebraic geometry,* Thm. 4.1.3*, to obtain the short exact sequence $$0 \to \Omega^k_{\mathbf{P}^n}(k) \to \mathcal{O}^{\oplus\binom{n+1}{k}}_{\mathbf{P}^n} \to \Omega^{k-1}_{\mathbf{P}^n}(k) \to 0$$ cf. Okonek/Schneider/Spindler, *Vector bundles on complex projective spaces*.